# scrolling down all filter menu linkedin with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i wanted to ask you. How can i scroll down the all filter menu in linkedin. I know how to scroll down a page using

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
```

but i don't know how to scroll inside a menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript to scroll an element the same way you scroll the window element:

```
let elem = document.querySelector('#myelem');

elem.scrollTo(0, elem.scrollHeight);
```

Which would look something like the following:

```
driver.execute_script("let elem = document.querySelector('#myelem');elem.scrollTo(0, elem.scrollHeight);")
```